# Showing a list of thoughts using c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I wish to display a list of thoughts instead of showing only 1 thought that changes on a daily basis. Is there a way to edit my codes to show changes by number of seconds instead of a new day?

How do I edit my codes below?

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;

namespace TOTD.TOTD
{
    public partial class TOTDUserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["QOTD"];
            SPListItemCollection collItem = oList.GetItems("Thought", "AuthorImage", "AuthorName","Head");

            Random random = new Random();
            int RndItem = random.Next(1, collItem.Count + 1);
            int LastDay = 0;
            int TOTD = 0;
            int CurrentDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear;

            try
            {

                LastDay = int.Parse(Application["LastDay"].ToString());
                TOTD = int.Parse(Application["TOTD"].ToString());


                if (LastDay != CurrentDay)
                {

                    Application["LastDay"] = CurrentDay;
                    Application["TOTD"] = RndItem;
                    SPListItem oItem = collItem[RndItem - 1];
                    this.ImgAuthor.ImageUrl = SPEncode.HtmlEncode
                        (oItem["AuthorImage"].ToString().TrimEnd('?', '.', ',', ' '));
                    this.lblTOTD.Text = oItem["Thought"].ToString();
                    this.lblAuthor.Text = SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oItem["AuthorName"].ToString());
                    this.lblNext.Text = SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oItem["Head"].ToString());
                }

                else
                {
                    SPListItem oItem = collItem[TOTD - 1];
                    this.ImgAuthor.ImageUrl = SPEncode.HtmlEncode
                        (oItem["AuthorImage"].ToString().TrimEnd('?', '.', ',', ' '));
                    this.lblTOTD.Text = oItem["Thought"].ToString();
                    this.lblAuthor.Text = SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oItem["AuthorName"].ToString());
                    this.lblNext.Text = SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oItem["Head"].ToString());
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                Application["LastDay"] = CurrentDay;
                Application["TOTD"] = RndItem;
                SPListItem oItem = collItem[RndItem - 1];
                this.ImgAuthor.ImageUrl = SPEncode.HtmlEncode
                    (oItem["AuthorImage"].ToString().TrimEnd('?', '.', ',', ' '));
                this.lblTOTD.Text = oItem["Thought"].ToString();
                this.lblAuthor.Text = SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oItem["AuthorName"].ToString());
                this.lblNext.Text = SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oItem["Head"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe insted of LastDay = int.... just have LastTime = int.... and if the current time is bigger for a certain number of seconds display what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save related DateTime and use [`Subtract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.subtract.aspx) Method:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(givenDate).TotalSeconds >= 1)
{
   Application["LastDay"] = DateTime.Now;
 // do stuff.
}...
```